# Android mediaplayer onSeekComplete not being called

Tags: android, media-player, seek

I'm writing a media player that will stream live and on demand streams.  It's mostly working, but for some reason I can't get seekTo(int) working correctly.  My problem is that when I call seekTo(int) I don't get my onSeekComplete callback.  I register my callback method in my onPrepared callback.

I should note that I'm also using MediaController and I've registered my MediaPlayer with MediaController.  When I seek by taping the seek bar, it goes through my MediaController and I do get my onSeekComplete callback in that scenario.  Here's my code.

```
package com.brockoli.android.hsdroid;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.MediaController.MediaPlayerControl;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class VideoPlayerActivity extends Activity implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, 
                                                             MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener, 
                                                             SurfaceHolder.Callback,
                                                             MediaController.MediaPlayerControl,
                                                             OnSeekCompleteListener {

    private MediaPlayer mp;
    private MediaController mc;
    private int width = 0;
    private int height = 0;
    private SurfaceView surface;
    private SurfaceHolder holder;
    private ProgressBar timeline = null;
    private boolean isPaused = false;
    private int mCurrentPosition = 0;

    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.video_player);

        if (getLastNonConfigurationInstance() != null) {
            mCurrentPosition = (Integer) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();         
        }

        mc = new MediaController(this);

        surface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_video);
        holder = surface.getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        isPaused = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        width = getScreenWidth();
        height = setHeightBasedOnWidth();

        isPaused = false;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (mp != null) {
            mp.release();
            mp = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
        int currentPosition = 0;
        if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) {
            currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
        }
        return currentPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        mc.show();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        String url = intent.getStringExtra("STREAM_ID");

        playVideo(url);

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        LayoutParams lp = surface.getLayoutParams();
        lp.width = width;
        lp.height = height;
        surface.setLayoutParams(lp);
        if (width != 0 && height != 0) {
            holder.setFixedSize(width, height);
            mc.setMediaPlayer(this);
            mc.setAnchorView(surface);

            handler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mc.setEnabled(true);
                    mc.show();
                }
            });

            Log.d("MEDIAPLAYER", "onPrepared start");
            mp.seekTo(mCurrentPosition);
            //mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    }

    private void playVideo(String url) {
            try {
                if (mp == null) {
                    mp = new MediaPlayer();
                    mp.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
                    mp.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
                    mp.setOnSeekCompleteListener(this);
                } else {
                    mp.stop();
                    mp.reset();
                }

                mp.setDataSource(url);
                mp.setDisplay(holder);
                mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);
                mp.prepareAsync();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int newWidth, int newHeight) {
/*      if (width != 0 && height != 0) {
            holder.setFixedSize(width, height);
            //mp.seekTo(mCurrentPosition);
            Log.d("MEDIAPLAYER", "onVideoSizeChanged start");
            //mediaPlayer.start();
        }
*/      
    }

    private Point getScreenSize() {
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        return size;
    }

    private int getScreenWidth() {
        return getScreenSize().x;
    }

    private int getScreenHeight() {
        return getScreenSize().y;
    }

    private int setHeightBasedOnWidth() {
        if (getScreenWidth() > getScreenHeight()) {
            return getScreenHeight();
        }
        return (int) (getScreenWidth()/1.6);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canPause() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canSeekBackward() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canSeekForward() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int getBufferPercentage() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCurrentPosition() {
        return mp.getCurrentPosition();
    }

    @Override
    public int getDuration() {
        return mp.getDuration();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isPlaying() {
        return mp.isPlaying();
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        mp.pause();
    }

    @Override
    public void seekTo(int pos) {
        mp.seekTo(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        Log.d("MEDIAPLAYER", "MediaController start");
        mp.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you check if control reaches the setOnSeekCompleteListener() call at all?

Comment: I set a breakpoint on setOnSeekCompleteListener() and it does hit it.  Also should note that I keep an eye on my media player object in memory and can see that the onSeekCompleteListener member is set to an object and not null, which tells me that it did set the listener.

Answer (score 1):

Devices implement MediaPlayer a little differently sometimes.  Check your onInfo listener to see if you're getting feedback.

Edit from comment:
I just tried it myself and it didn't work for me either in my app. The way around it for me was, especially if your media was already playing when the seek event started, if you see the currentPosition increasing again then you know that seeking has been completed.

Comment: I've registered the onInfoListener callback in the same place where I register my bufferListener, onSeekCompleteListener, onErrorListener, etc, and that also is never getting called.  I've tried also just inlining it mp.setInfoListener(new MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener() { @Override Public void onInfo(... } Still no luck.  Really can't see where I'm going wrong here.

Comment: It's not you apparently.  I read a bug report on my way home that described your situation.

Comment: Hmm.. Ok, I will try compiling against a lower API level.  Surely this had to be working at some point.

Comment: I just bypassed my media player entirely and launched the Android video player with Intent.setAction(INTENT.ACTION_VIEW) and Intent.setDataAndType(Uri, "video/*");

This launches my selected stream in the stock Android video player and I can confirm there is no buffering shown at all.  So I guess this just isn't working.

Comment: I just tried it myself and it didn't work for me either in my app.  The way around it for me was, especially if your media was already playing when the seek event started, if you see the currentPosition increasing again then you know that seeking has been completed.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit old but the issue is still relevant.
The solution I found is to run a loop that checks if the MediaPlayer is currently playing and if it doesn't than I release it.

```
        mediaPlayer.start()
        while (mediaPlayer.isPlaying) {
            Thread.sleep(500)
        }
        mediaPlayer.release()
```

I'm not afraid of occupying the thread since I don't run the MediaPlayer on the main thread.